# Restart System and Run Powershell Script without logging in

Tags: powershell

I have multiple restarts between script blocks, the problem is on every restart the user is required to key in their credentials, and log in.

Is there any way where once the script is being executed it can login to system without username and password? We would want to hardcode username and password in the script itself.

The script helps in achieving the following:

1. Run Script Block
2. Restart
3. Run Next Script Block

But this requires user to log in after restart. Until then the process is under halt. I am looking for a way to automate the login process as well... I know it creates security threat, but this is something that is necessary for the process I am supposed to achieve.

```
#Code which will run script with admin privileges
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}

# Temp Folder
if (!(Get-Item d:\temp -ea ignore)) { mkdir d:\temp }

$dropperscript = 'D:\temp\dropper.ps1'

$dropper = @'
#############################################
###        Configuration Variables        ###
                                            #
# Put any variables you'll use here
                                            # 
###                                       ###
#############################################

# Static Variables
$countfile = 'd:\temp\bootcount.txt'
$bootbatch = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\dropper.bat'
$dropperscript = 'd:\temp\dropper.ps1'

#################
##### Setup #####

# Bootstrap Batch
if (!(Get-Item $bootbatch -ea ignore)) {
$x='PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '''
$y=' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\temp\dropper.ps1""'' -Verb RunAs}"'

$x+$y| Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM'

}

# Boot Count
if (Get-Item $countfile -ea ignore) {
    [int]$bootcount = Get-Content $countfile
    if ($bootcount -match "^\d{1,2}$") { ([int]$bootcount) ++ }
    else { $bootcount = 1 }
}
else { $bootcount = 1 }
$bootcount | Out-File $countfile


switch ($bootcount) {

    1 {
   $File="D:\temp\Log.txt"
    Get-Date | Out-File $File -Append 
   Get-Process | Out-File $File -Append 
        Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     --REBOOT--     ###############
    }

    2 {
       $File="D:\temp\Log.txt"
    Get-Date | Out-File $File -Append 
   Get-Process | Out-File $File -Append 
        Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     --REBOOT--     ###############
    }

    3 {
        $File="D:\temp\Log.txt"
    Get-Date | Out-File $File -Append 
    Get-Process('\\itdsl\MSNPLAT\Gold\MSNPATCH\msnpatch.exe') | Out-File $File -Append 

       Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     Restart    ################
    }

    4{
    $File="D:\temp\Log.txt"
    Get-Date | Out-File $File -Append 
    Get-Process| Out-File $File -Append 

       Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############      --END--      ################
 }

    default {
        # Dropper is complete; clean up
        rm $countfile
        rm $bootbatch
        rm $dropperscript
    }
}
'@

# Drop and run Dropper

$dropper | Out-File $dropperscript -Encoding 'OEM'

Invoke-Expression $dropperscript
```

Comment: I would use [PowerShell Remoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands) instead. There's no unattended logged on computer to be a security risk then.

Comment: Why could you not make this into a scheduled task to run on reboot? Is there anything here that has to run as a user?

Comment: We tried that,But The Server we are dealing with is not allowed any remote sessions(Some Policy).

Comment: @Matt Yes,We have certain commands that are to be run as user itself.(In the code where Get-Process is written, Will be replaced by certain set of commands)

Comment: I would rather suggest using the powershell workflow, which is designed for such cases and can survive a reboot. 
`By design, workflows can be long-running, repeatable, frequent, parallelizable, interruptible, stoppable, and restartable. They can be suspended and resumed; they can also continue after an unexpected interruption, such as a network outage or computer restart.` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134242(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @Adamar Can you Please Suggest an edit on the existing Script ?

Comment: Switching to workflows basically means you'll be rewriting the script from scratch.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what his script is doing now. All i see is get-log, reboot, get-log again, reboot, install patch, reboot, get-log again. Why are there two reboots -before- the patch installation? Presuming it's not a one-off thing and needs to run on many machines, i think it's well worth rewriting a script until it suits your needs.

Comment: I would suggest reading through the Hey Scripting Guy blogposts about workflow, specifically this one that deals with reboots.  
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/23/powershell-workflows-restarting-the-computer/